# cURL php Get return 401 with oauth2 after get token

Tags: php, wordpress, api, php-curl, http-status-code-401

I generate token with OAuth2 authentication. Then, when I execute get to retrieve the data, I got an http code: 401. The function `curl_getinfo` throws this message.

```
array(26) { 
    ["url"]=> string(50) "https://endpoint" 
    ["content_type"]=> string(16) "application/json" 
    ["http_code"]=> int(401) 
    ["header_size"]=> int(617) 
    ["request_size"]=> int(176) 
    ["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
    ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
    ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
    ["total_time"]=> float(0.177855) 
    ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.02825) 
    ["connect_time"]=> float(0.045129) 
    ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.0831) 
    ["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
    ["size_download"]=> float(84) 
    ["speed_download"]=> float(472) 
    ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
    ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
    ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) 
    ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.177786) 
    ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
    ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["primary_ip"]=> string(13) "****" 
    ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["primary_port"]=> int(443) 
    ["local_ip"]=> string(13) "*****" 
    ["local_port"]=> int(34886) 
} 
Failed to retrieve data. Response code: Array
```

Any idea please for this problem.

This is my code, I got token, then I passed `access_token` to get data from endpoint. I got token with POST, but the problem is when I want to retrieve data.

```
<?php

$issued_at = time();
$expires_in = 3600;
$expiration_time = $issued_at + $expires_in;
$current_time = time();

// Token endpoint URL
$token_url = "***/oauth2/token";

// Client ID and secret
$client_id = "****";
$client_secret = "*****";

// Define the POST request to retrieve the token
$post_data = array(
    "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
    "client_id" => $client_id,
    "client_secret" => $client_secret
);

// Initialize cURL
// Make the request to retrieve the token
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === false) {
    die(curl_error($curl));
}

// Check the response code
$response_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($response_code != 200) {
    die("Failed to retrieve token. Response code: " . $response_code);
}

// Decode the response to retrieve the access token
$response_data = json_decode($response, true);

if (!array_key_exists("access_token", $response_data)) {
    die("Failed to retrieve access token");
}

$access_token = $response_data["access_token"];

//var_dump($access_token);

// Close the cURL connection
curl_close($curl);


if ($current_time > $expiration_time) {
    // Token has expired
    die("Token has expired: " . $access_token );

} else {
    // Token is still valid



// Define the GET request URL
$get_url = "endpoint";

// Define the headers for the GET request
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

// Make the GET request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

// Check the response code
$response_code = curl_getinfo($ch);

//var_dump($response_code);

if ($response_code != 200) {
    die("Failed to retrieve data. Response code: " . $response_code);
}

// Decode the response data
$response_data = json_decode($response, true);

// Close the cURL connection
curl_close($ch);

// Output the response data
var_dump($response_data);
            
}
```

Comment: `curl_getinfo` gets you information mostly relating to the protocol-specific aspects of the request. Have you checked what the actual response _body_ contained yet? That is probably likely to contain a human-readable error message.

Comment: I got this error "Failed to retrieve data. Response code: Array"

Comment: As the actual response from the API? That rather sounds like a custom error message created by _your_ code, and followed up with a botched attempt to make a basic debug output (you can not output an array in any sensible way using echo, that will only get you the _word_ "Array" - use `var_dump`.) And I did not ask about the HTTP response status code, I asked about the content of the response body.

Comment: error "array(2) { ["error"]=> string(13) "invalid_token" ["error_description"]=> string(36) "The access token provided is invalid" }"

Comment: Then you are probably passing it wrong (assuming it isn't actually invalid) - so include some relevant details then, about how exactly you are making the request in the first place.

Comment: I added the example I try it .

Comment: What kind of request are you making here, to what kind of endpoint? Is it supposed to work with a client token, or does it maybe need a user token instead?

Comment: Yes,Is it supposed to work with a client token , the type of endpoint is Get

Comment: Can you do a full dump of the `$response_data` you got from the token endpoint call? What else is in there, any info regarding expiry / validity time of the token or something? Not sure what service or API you are using there, does it maybe have a "debug token" endpoint?

Comment: information about token "array(4) { ["access_token"]=> string(40) "**********************************" ["expires_in"]=> int(3600) ["token_type"]=> string(6) "Bearer" ["scope"]=> string(11) "read, write" }"

Comment: other information in doecimentation for api "The authentication is managed through Oauth2.
To request the token you have to make a POST request to <installation_domain>/oauth2/token"

Comment: Hm, that all sounds like it should work, how you are passing the bearer token with the request also appears to be the absolutely usual way. (The API _does_ accept it via an authorization header, I assume? Sometimes they only accept it as a GET or POST parameter named `access_token`, or something similar.)

Comment: In documentation it'is indicated to use token in header "The token that is returned must be inserted in every following call through the Authorization header."

Comment: Looks to me like you are doing everything as you are supposed to then. Might be time to contact their support?